# Resolving DNS & MX Records

Tags: email, dns, mail-server, email-server

I am new to the community and I really need your assistance to resolve some complicated issues with DNS/MX Records.
My client's website is designed and hosted in Wix with mydomain.com and pointing to mydomain2.com (hosted on GoDaddy). The mail server with a CPanel is on another host abc.defvps.com with a Shared IP address 123.4.567.890.

With the name servers on the GoDaddy account are pointing to ns1.abc.defvps.com and ns2.abc.defvps.com. I have noticed the site appears as a thin stripe on Mobile viewports.

When the name servers are restored to GoDaddy default nameservers, the site appears normal but the Email servers fail to work.

Please I'd appreciate any assistance to quickly resolve this for my client. Thank you.

Regards,
MV

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SuperUser.

Nameservers should point to wherever your DNS is hosted which generally is where you bought the domain. Your DNS needs to have entries for your website (A records) and mail servers (MX records). Your A record for the website needs to point to the address designated by the web host. Your MX records need to point to whatever addresses designated by the mail host. Once you do that, everything should work fine.

Chances are when you pointed the Nameservers to the mail host, it was being directed to a default site that had zero to do with Wix.

More info here: https://www.godaddy.com/garage/configuring-dns-for-email-a-quick-beginners-guide/